# Best way to fastly refresh text in a GTK window

Tags: gtk3

I am building a GTK window with text that need to be updated, say 10 times per second, every time it receives a data from a GPS.

Which kind of widget should I use?

GTK-label is safe for this kind of operation or are there other more suitable widgets?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no difference wich widget to use. GtkLabel is ok, I use it for GPS data, but it's updated once per second. I doubt it will be readable if it gets updated every 100 ms. You may want to use a GtkTextView and print every gps sentence on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GtkDrawingArea and draw to it using cairo.
That way it could be way higher than 10 drawings/s.
Cairo has native text operations. 
You could even design your own widget.
Even if you're using python or any other language that cairo and gtk have bindings for, thanks to "gobject introspection".